# How to add Buttons and other stuff like Image Viiew in default Bottom Tab Activity of Android

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

I am new to Android development and have created a new project with the ‘Bottom Tab Navigation’,  unlike the blank activity where I get a java class and a layout activity and to put Buttons in the onCreate method the HomeFragment and HomeViewModel doesn’t have any of those fields.  I want to add a few buttons And Image Views to them...Cam anyone please help me by telling where to put code like  `private Button xyz;` and then  `xyz=findViewById()`

Comment: Are you talking about Bottom navigation bar? and image on it right?

Comment: Right upto a level...actually I want to add buttons and image view inside the particular home fragment and I am unable to find it’s appropriate java file where to put that code (inside HomeFragment.java or HomeViewModel.java?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add image and title in bottom navigation bar by going inside this path

```
res/menu/ bottom_navigation_menu.xml
```

You don't need to create the object of these buttons and texts. but if you want to access these items then define BottomNavigationView by findViewById() then call below method on this object.

```
BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()
```

You need to implement onNavigationItemSelected inside this which will give you the ID's of all bar menus. I hope this will help.

Comment: Actually I want to add buttons and image view inside the particular home fragment and I am unable to find it’s appropriate java file where to put that code (inside HomeFragment.java or HomeViewModel.java?) –

Comment: You need to add the ui inside view layer that is activity or fragment.

Comment: I hope you got your answer. Could you please accept and upvote.

Comment: Actually a beginner...Hence can only ‘Accept’